# How to use leftJoin in Laravel for case?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following code:

```
$registrations = User::where(function ($query) use ($request) {
   if (!is_null($request->region) && $request->region !== '0') {
      $query->where('region', $request->region);
   }
})->get();
```

How to join `User` result with another model `Clients` with `Left Join` condition?

I tried this way:

```
$registrations = User->join('clients', 'clients.id', '=', 'user.id')->where(...
```

Comment: User is a class and not an object and hence you cannot use -> so you should use :: for calling functions on it

Comment: Read docs before asking a question

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation first: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins.

```
$registrations = User::where(....)
    ->join('clients', 'clients.id', '=', 'user.id')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could catch it by reading [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins)

```
$users = DB::table('users')
->leftJoin('clients', 'users.id', '=', 'clients.user_id')
->where('','')
->get();
```